# How to connect JProfiler to an application running on remote OC4J?

Tags: jprofiler, oc4j

Problem: the OC4J instance will now not start up after configuring for JProfiler.

Configuration:
OC4J 10.1.3.4.0, Java 1.5.0_06 (32-bit), remote server is Linux x86/AMD64, nowait. Manual sync of config, and I've copied over the config.xml from the .jprofiler directory. Default port of 8849.

In the ORACLE_HOME/opmn/logs/default_group~ifactory~default_group~1.log file, I see

```
13/03/19 14:48:42 Start process
--------
JProfiler> Protocol version 37
JProfiler> Using JVMTI
JProfiler> 32-bit library
JProfiler> Don't wait for frontend to connect.
JProfiler> Using config file /icu/ias/dev/ifactory/jprofiler/config.xml (id: 110)
JProfiler> Could not find session with id: 110
```

from ORACLE_HOME/opmn/conf/config.xml:

```
        <process-type id="ifactory" module-id="OC4J" status="enabled">
           <module-data>
              <category id="start-parameters">
                 <data id="java-options" value="-server -Xmx1024m -Djava.security.policy=$ORACLE_HOME/j2ee/ifactory/config/java2.policy -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhttp.webdir.enable=false -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Dlog4j.debug=true -agentpath:/icu/ias/dev/ifactory/jprofiler/bin/linux-x86/libjprofilerti.so=port=8849,nowait,id=110,config=/icu/ias/dev/ifactory/jprofiler/config.xml "/>
              </category>
              <category id="stop-parameters">
                 <data id="java-options" value="-Djava.security.policy=$ORACLE_HOME/j2ee/ifactory/config/java2.policy -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhttp.webdir.enable=false"/>
              </category>
           </module-data>
           <start timeout="600" retry="2"/>
           <stop timeout="120"/>
           <restart timeout="720" retry="2"/>
           <port id="default-web-site" range="12501-12600" protocol="ajp"/>
           <port id="rmi" range="12401-12500"/>
           <port id="rmis" range="12701-12800"/>
           <port id="jms" range="12601-12700"/>
           <process-set id="default_group" numprocs="1"/>
        </process-type>
```

So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Apparently I had a slightly older version of the config.xml.